# How to Generate random number within specific number

Tags: php

I need to generate three different random numbers without repeating, Three different random numbers need to be within 10 of the answer

```
        for the sample IQ Question: 4,6 ,9,6,14,6,... Ans:19
        A: random numbers 
        B: random numbers
        C: random numbers
        D: random numbers
one of them is the answer
```

I am now using the following code but sometimes the numbers are repeated, I have tried shuffle But which one is really random cannot satisfy random numbers need to be within 10 of the answer

```
$ans = $row['answer'];

$a = rand (1,10);
$a1 = rand($ans-$a   ,$ans+$a);
$a2 = rand($ans-$a  ,$ans+$a);
$a3 = rand($ans-$a  ,$ans+$a);
```

Comment: _the number cannot be smaller and larger than 10_ ??? 10 is not very random if thats the only number you allow

Comment: If you dont want the same random number more than once, thats not random, but all you have to do is check that the new random number is not already in the other variables. It would be easier if you stored the numbers in an array

Comment: 10 the answer is 10  --  https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/images/f/fe/random_number.png

Comment: @IMSoP oh, Thank , comment  and set duplicates 
 actually, I reference these 3 questions before my post, google the first  result is to use shuffle, but did not solve my problem

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes, I need to generate random Answers. and  the Answer cannot be smaller and larger than 10 for each other option  , actually I have tried it very early to use shuffle, but shuffle cannot satisfy the requirement

Comment: @PingLee Neither smaller nor larger than x always results in x.  Please rethink this requirement, because it's unclear.

Comment: @Daedalus, The Requirement file is said. 'The differences among the choices cannot be larger than 10.'

Comment: Ah now it is clearer, so if answer is 100 then the random numbers must be in the range 90 to 110. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @PingLee Can you include more details of what you tried with `shuffle`? I think that approach can still work for you, but I might still be missing something.

Answer (score 2):

As shown in previous answers (e.g. [Generating random numbers without repeats](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17778723/157957), [Simple random variable php without repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43496931/157957), [Generating random numbers without repeats](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17778723/157957)) you can use `shuffle` to randomise a range, and then pick three items using `array_slice`.

The difference in your case is how you define the range:

- Rather than 1 to 10, you want `$ans - 10` to `$ans + 10`
- You want to exclude the right answer

One way to build that is as two ranges: lower limit up to but not including right answer, and right answer + 1 up to upper limit.

```
function generate_wrong_answers($rightAnswer) {
    // Generate all wrong guesses from 10 below to 10 above, 
    // but miss out the correct answer
    $wrongAnswers = array_merge(
        range($rightAnswer - 10, $rightAnswer - 1),
        range($rightAnswer + 1, $rightAnswer + 10)
    );
    
    // Randomise
    shuffle($wrongAnswers);
    
    // Pick 3
    return array_slice($wrongAnswers, 0, 3);
}
```